# How do you combine two objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

If I have two Javascript objects which I am using as a list of key-value pairs:

```
var a = {a:1};
var b = {b:2};
```

what is the most efficient way to combine them into a third object which contains the properties of both?

```
var c = {a:1, b:2};
```

I don't mind if either or both of `a` and `b` are modified in the process.

Comment: If a property contains another object or an array, do you want a new copy or a reference to that property in the new object?

Comment: What question is this a duplicate of?

Comment: var a = {a:1, c:4};
 var b = {b:2, f:9, d:4};
 
 var c = combine(a, b);
 
 function combine(array1, array2) {
  for (key in array2) {
   array1[key] = array2[key];
  }  
  return array1
 }

Comment: @Alison: Look at the top of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 4):

You can do simply this :

```
   var c = {};
   for (var key in a) {
      c[key] = a[key];
   }
   for (var key in b) {
      c[key] = b[key];
   }
```

---

If you want to do a deep merging (assuming you don't want to copy the functions and prototypes), you can use this :

```
  function goclone(source) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(source)==='[object Array]') {
            var clone = [];
            for (var i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
                if (source[i]) clone[i] = goclone(source[i]);
            }
            return clone;
        } else if (typeof(source)=="object") {
            var clone = {};
            for (var prop in source) {
                if (source[prop]) {
                    var firstChar = prop.charAt(0);
                    clone[prop] = goclone(source[prop]);
                }
            }
            return clone;
        } else {
            return source;
        }
    }


   var c = {};
   for (var key in a) {
      c[key] = goclone(a[key]);
   }
   for (var key in b) {
      c[key] = goclone(b[key]);
   }
```

But frankly I never saw the use for a deep merging in javascript...

Comment: This will only work for primitive data types. Any object type will only be referenced.

Comment: Copying even non enumerable properties? Not taking into account nested objects? Oh, come on! :-)

Comment: Deep cloning if different from cloning...

Comment: No one said anything about deep copies...

Comment: @JosephSilber: It still works with reference types. You're assuming a reference to the same object is not desired.

Comment: Why those downvotes ? Deep copying is rarely needed and wasn't requested. Even deep cloning is rare...

Comment: Now with deep merging...

Comment: @dystroy - What is `$.isArray`? Are you using jQuery? Then just use `$.extend`, and be over and done with...

Comment: Making a isArray is easy... I'll add it. edit : done.

Comment: Or you can copy jQuery's source and be done with it, seeing how much code you've written (it's almost as much as jQuery's extend).

Comment: I've put a lot of code because somebody wasn't satisfied with OP's question and required deep merge.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - Copying jQuery's source is an option, but you'll have to hunt down all of jQuery's other functions being used in there. Here's a **great** tool for that: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=extend - ring me up when you're done.

Comment: Still not using `hasOwnProperty` :/ @JosephSilber yeah I was hesitating whether I'd put this code here or not

Comment: Please, people asking for deep cloning or speaking of hasOwnProperty, just read the question *"If I have two Javascript objects which I am using as a list of key-value pairs:"*.

Comment: var c= $.extend({}, a, b);